# Intervals that contains at least one prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is it true that for all integer $n > 1$ and $k ≤ n$ there exists a
prime number in the interval $[kn,(k + 1)n]$?

For which $n$ and $k$ natural numbers it's true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true, according to [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Moses/moses1.pdf). In fact, if we require that at least one prime is in the interval $(kn,(k+1)n)$ for *all* $n>1$, then, if $k<100000000$, only
$$
k=1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 14
$$
are possible. 
In general, there are many articles on this topic available on the web, some of which may not be reliable (vixra.org). I would recommend the blog of Terry Tao
[here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/long-gaps-between-primes/) about gaps between primes.  
The same question also has been asked
[here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_always_a_prime_in_the_interval_kn_k_1n_or_not_n_1_and_a_fixed_integer_k_n_Sequence_of_questions).

Comment: I remember that I read a paper for the case $k=4$.

Comment: For the case $k = 4$: there isn't a prime in the interval $(4n, 5n)$ when $n = 2$ - that is, 9 is not prime.  But this will be true for sufficiently large $n$, and it appears that $n \ge 2$ suffices.  Similarly it appears that for $k = 6$, $n = 5$ suffices - that is, $(6n, 7n)$ contains a prime for $n \ge 5$ but $(6 \cdot 4, 7 \cdot 4)$ doesn't.  In general for any given $k$ there will be some $n$ above which $(kn, (k+1)n)$ contains a prime for all $n$.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Yes, right. But the question says "Is it true that for *all* integers $n>1$ and *all* $k\le n$ there exists a prime number in the interval..." For the second part there are the answers for the duplicate question linked.